# How to combine a query with an INNER JOIN to a subquery containing a RANK function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank

I have a query A that returns basic stats by using an `INNER JOIN` on two tables (sites & data) and calculating min, max, count, etc. I also have a query B that retrieves the latest value from a single table (data).

But I'm attempting to join the two queries so that I can display latest value along with the min, max, count values. I've tried basic unions but I think I'm missing something.

Query A:

```
SELECT 
    xc_data1.station_id, 
    xc_data1.sensorname, 
    xc_sites.site_comment,
    xc_sites.SITE_LONG_NAME,
    xc_sites.IPADDRESS,
    COUNT(xc_data1.time_tag) AS result_count,
    MIN(xc_data1.time_tag) AS start_time,
    MAX(xc_data1.time_tag) AS last_time
FROM 
    [XC_DATA].[dbo].[xc_sites] 
INNER JOIN 
    [XC_DATA].[dbo].[xc_data1] ON xc_sites.station_id = xc_data1.station_id
WHERE
    time_tag > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
GROUP BY 
    xc_data1.station_id, xc_data1.sensorname,
    xc_sites.site_comment, xc_sites.SITE_LONG_NAME, xc_sites.IPADDRESS
ORDER BY 
    last_time desc
```

Query B:

```
SELECT 
    station_id, 
    sensorname, 
    time_tag,
    orig_value AS Last_record
FROM   
    (SELECT 
         station_id, sensorname, time_tag, orig_value,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY station_id ORDER BY time_tag DESC) AS rk
     FROM   
         [XC_DATA].[dbo].[xc_data1]) t
WHERE  
    rk = 1 
    AND time_tag > DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
ORDER BY
    time_tag DESC
```

Result of query A:

| station_id | sensorname | site_comment | SITE_LONG_NAME | IPADDRESS | result_count | start_time | last_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 011370 | RAIN | marshy | Dead Marshes | 10.123.192.6 | 2062 | 7/14/2022 11:00 | 7/21/2022 14:55 |
| 011369 | RAIN | sandy | Hobbit Hole | 10.123.192.56 | 2061 | 7/14/2022 11:00 | 7/21/2022 14:55 |

Result of query B:

| station_id | sensorname | time_tag | Last_record |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 011370 | RAIN | 7/21/2022 14:55 | 0.01 |
| 011369 | RAIN | 7/21/2022 14:55 | 0.05 |

Desired result:

| station_id | sensorname | site_comment | SITE_LONG_NAME | IPADDRESS | result_count | Last_Record | start_time | last_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 011370 | RAIN | marshy | Dead Marshes | 10.123.192.6 | 2062 | 0.01 | 7/14/2022 11:00 | 7/21/2022 14:55 |
| 011369 | RAIN | sandy | Hobbit Hole | 10.123.192.56 | 2061 | 0.05 | 7/14/2022 11:00 | 7/21/2022 14:55 |

Comment: The `station_id` doesn't match between A and B queries. Are they meant to? If so, what I would probably do here is turn each of those queries into a sub-query and join those together.

Comment: Check again your sample data and expected results. How is station_id=011284 linked to station_id=011284? Also, where do 0.01 and 0.5 come from in Last_Record?

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE

```
With QueryA as
(SELECT xc_data1.station_id, 
xc_data1.sensorname, 
xc_sites.site_comment,
xc_sites.SITE_LONG_NAME,
xc_sites.IPADDRESS,
count(xc_data1.time_tag) as result_count,
min(xc_data1.time_tag) as start_time,
max(xc_data1.time_tag) as last_time
FROM [XC_DATA].[dbo].[xc_sites] INNER JOIN [XC_DATA].[dbo].[xc_data1] ON   xc_sites.station_id = xc_data1.station_id
where time_tag > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
GROUP BY xc_data1.station_id, xc_data1.sensorname,xc_sites.site_comment,     xc_sites.SITE_LONG_NAME, xc_sites.IPADDRESS
order by last_time desc
),
QueryB as
(
SELECT station_id, 
sensorname, 
time_tag,
orig_value as Last_record
FROM   (SELECT station_id, sensorname, time_tag, orig_value,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY station_id ORDER BY time_tag DESC) AS rk
    FROM   [XC_DATA].[dbo].[xc_data1]) t
WHERE  rk = 1 and time_tag > DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
ORDER BY time_tag desc
)

Select *
From QueryA A
Join QueryB B on A.station_id = B.station_id and A.sensorname = B.sensorname
```

Comment: Yeah, this should work, though I think the join condition for sensorname is unnecessary. Also, depending on the number of rows these queries produce and how it's to be used, temp tables may be a better solution, but that's another issue entirely(performance).